# How do I set up a report that shows number of clients by age group when their age is stored by date of birth in Microsoft Access

Tags: database-design, ms-access, reporting

I am working on setting up a new database in Microsoft Access for a food locker it will be used for client input as well as tracking client visits. One of the monthly reports they need is how many clients (including all family members on their account) have visited each month separated into the following age groups:0-3, 4-17, 18-61 and 62 and over. It seems this will have to be a multi-step process as the ages will be stored only as the date of birth, but I wasn't sure if there was something straight forward that I am missing as I am fairly new to Access.

Comment: Just provide a table for storing sets of age groups.

Comment: [group by range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876334/group-by-range-ms-access-database) and [calc age by birthday](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/Concepts/Date-Time/calculate-age)